# How Can I Monitor Internet Usage?

Tags: release-freya, applications, monitoring, internet

I need to know my bandwidth and consumed internet bandwidth and downloaded data size like that.  I tried this, but its not getting total downloaded packs size.

[AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532424/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-usage)

Comment: See here if useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-internet-download-usage

Comment: Also see http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/

Comment: let me see, any widget level app for it to display always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on "Conky". At the beginning it seems not to be easy to configure - but there are many templates you can use. [Here](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/07/conky-collection-for-ubuntulinux.html) you can find many templates - of course you can adjust them to your needs

Also usefull is "Conky Manager" (http://ubuntuguide.net/install-conky-manager-2-0-2-ubuntu-1404).

To have an idea how a conky can look like, see my desktop:
[image: Desktop with customized System-Flair-Conky]

The red recangle shows the current up- / down-speed and the total size of uploaded / downloaded data. These values will be resetted after reboot.

@Daniel: Sorry for posting a comment rather than as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Actually the question is mine. Let me check it and get back to you.  By the way your desktop looks awesome

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.  I have found that the most simple one is to install

```
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```

Then click on resources.  I have it selected in the autostart apps and just alt + tab when I want to know.  I used to use the Gnome addon, but I don't use gnome anymore (hint devs).  On the downside, it is only measures each session.

[image]